# CSS Pseudo Element Changes Height When Moving its Position

Tags: html, css, css-position, pseudo-element

I'm creating tabs, where each link inside the tab list is in a div with a border - something like:

[image]

In order to hide the bottom border of the tabset below the selected tab, I'm adding a pseudo element (`:after`) that is the full width of the link, and whose height is the same as the bottom border (2px), and also has a `bottom` value of negative the border height (-2px). I'm running into an issue where, depending on the position (`bottom` value) of the pseudo element, its rendered height changes. If I set its height to 2px, it fluctuates between 1px and 2px, and does this every 2px when moving its position.

For example, at `bottom: 3px`, it looks like this (I've made the background red for illustration purposes):

[image]

But then if I set `bottom: 2px`, I get this:

[image]

I see this behavior on both firefox and chrome. [Here's a codepen illustrating](http://codepen.io/joelbyrd/pen/ENwYzP).

And here's an inline snippet of the same code:

```css
.main-container {
 padding: 50px;
 font-family: arial;
}

.link-container {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid #000;
}

a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000;
 padding: 5px 5px 15px;
}


a:hover {
 background: #ccc;
}

a:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 height: 2px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 2px;
 background: red;
}

a.tab2:after {
 bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="link-container">
  <a class="tab1" href="#">Test Tab</a>
 </div>
 <div class="link-container">
  <a class="tab2" href="#">Test Tab</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

What's going on?

Comment: If you don't want a bottom border...why not just remove it?

Comment: However, as I understand it, absolutely positioned elements ignore the borders of their "relative" elements when it comes to computing their position. In other words..`bottom:0` will be **inside** any border.

Comment: @Paulie_D - b/c there is a border on the whole nav list that extends across the screen, so it's really *this* border that I need to hide for just the section below the active tab.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's still relevant or not, but I run into the same problem and I couldn't find any solution online so I came up with my own - I think this problem related either with float size of the parent element, either with something else.

But adding "transform: scaleY(1.0001);" to your pseudo-element seems to work for me

```css
.main-container {
    padding: 50px;
    font-family: arial;
}

.link-container {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 5px 15px;
}


a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}

a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 2px;
    background: red;
    transform: scaleY(1.0001);
}

a.tab2:after {
    bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="link-container">
        <a class="tab1" href="#">Test Tab</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
        <a class="tab2" href="#">Test Tab</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your browser is zoomed in on the page. Make sure that you're viewing the page at 100% size by clicking ctrl + 0 and see if the height still changes with the position.

Other than that, if I understand correctly what you want to achieve, you're making things much more complicated than needed.

Firstly, unless you have a reason, the link-container divs are not needed. You can just put the links directly as childs of the main-container div and add borders to them directly.

Secondly, you can just use border-bottom and set it to whatever you like.

Comment: It's not a zoom issue - you can see in my code snippet above - run it yourself and you'll see the height difference between the 2 lines.

Comment: No height difference for me when I move the position around with my zoom at 100%. However I do see the height changing when I move the position and I'm zoomed in. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Just checked on FireFox and same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do it like this: Remove the pseudo element completely and reduce the border to three sides:

```
.link-container {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Here it is in your snippet:

```css
.main-container {
 padding: 50px;
 font-family: arial;
}

.link-container {
 display: inline-block;
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
 border-left: 2px solid #000;
 border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000;
 padding: 5px 5px 15px;
}


a:hover {
 background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="link-container">
  <a class="tab1" href="#">Test Tab</a>
 </div>
 <div class="link-container">
  <a class="tab2" href="#">Test Tab</a>
 </div>
</div>
```